# unknow ERROR (in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given)

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters

am using following function to state friend function between two user but i get following error

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PDO friends 2\userData.php on line 60
```

line 60 is this `if (in_array($friend, $f)) {` and function is bellow

```
function isFriend($user, $friend) {
    $isFriend = false;
    $friends = getUsersFriends($user);
    foreach ($friends as $f) {
        if (in_array($friend, $f)) {
            $isFriend = true;
        }
    }
    return $isFriend;
}
```

Comment: if its a flat array, no need for `foreach`, just simple `in_array($friends, $friend)`, just be careful, its case sensitive

Comment: `print_r($friends);` and show us the structure

Comment: @Ghost: That should probably be `in_array($friend, $friends)`.

Comment: @NisseEngström yeah, swapped the arguments, but you get my idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the comments above, if `$friends` is indeed just a flat array, just use `in_array` alone. No need for `foreach`. What happens is, you're applying `in_array` of each string which doesn't make sense. You apply `in_array` to the whole array of strings:

```
function isFriend($user, $friend) {
    return in_array($friend, getUsersFriends($user));
}
```

Take note that `Sanoj != sanoj`. It might be better to change all the caps of the collection of friends to compare against the `strtolower`ed `$friend`:

Idea:

```
function isFriend($user, $friend) {
    return in_array(strtolower($friend), array_map('strtolower', getUsersFriends($user)));
}
```

Comment: @sanojlawrence sure glad this helped